# React Loses "this" In Callback From Third Party Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I'm using the Quagga.js library to decode barcodes from the webcam.

Everything is working fine except in the "OnDetected" function that Quagga calls when a barcode is scanned. When coming from a callback, the React code loses access to the "this" of the React Component.

Below is the code and the issue comes into play in the `onDetected(result)` function when called as a callback from the `Quagga.onDetected(this.onDetected);`

If feel like this issue is more of a misunderstanding of React itself rather than the library having an issue. If this is the case, some general principles for working with Third Party Libraries would be greatly appreciated.

```
onDetected(result) {
    this.processBarcode(result["codeResult"]["code"]); //<- "this" refers to the callback, not the react component
}

processBarcode(barcode) {
    if (barcode.startsWith("US-")) {
        this.setState({user_barcode: barcode});
    } else {
        this.setState({shop_drawing_barcode: barcode});
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Quagga.init({
            inputStream: {
                name: "Live",
                type: "LiveStream",
                target: document.querySelector('#scanner_window'),    // Or '#yourElement' (optional)
                constraints: {
                    width: 480,
                    height: 480,
                    facingMode: "environment" // or user
                }
            },
            numOfWorkers: 1,
            decoder: {
                readers: ["code_128_reader"]
            }, locate: true

        }, (err) => {
            Quagga.start();
            console.log("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
            resolve();
        })
    })).then(() => {
        //Set the callback
        Quagga.onDetected(this.onDetected);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide your full code, as it's not clear how `this` should refer to the callback like you commented

Comment: @GalAbra At the very bottom you'll see the line that says `        Quagga.onDetected(this.onDetected);` this is where im setting the callback

Comment: Did you `bind` the functions to the component?

Comment: @GalAbra I did not. That was the key to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The this.onDetected might be passing the function without binding to any this. You have to explicitly bind this.onDetected

```js
Quagga.onDetected(this.onDetected.bind(this));
```

Comment: So good! Thank you so much. Also i just discovered that if you use an arrow function to declare onDetected, it passes "this" to it.